# WP Cron registers hook without any action (does not call the function)

Tags: plugin-development

I'm creating my first Wordpress plugin and have been being stuck for hours with this problem... Hopefully someone can help me find out what's failing!

This is the code:

```
//If event is not scheduled, do it. Adjusted to every_min while in development. 
if (!wp_next_scheduled('wp_stocks_weekly_event')) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_min', 'wp_stocks_weekly_event' );
}


//Function to run weekly
function wp_stocks_update_all_stocks() {

    wp_mail('me@e-mail.im', 'Automatic email', 'Weekly cron wp_stocks_update_all_stocks has been succesfully executed!');
}


//Create a custom hook and links a function to execute
add_action( 'wp_stocks_weekly_event', 'wp_stocks_update_all_stocks' );
```

The previous code successfully creates the hook and the cron job. As I can see in a cron job plugin, everything is there:

[image]

...except the action linked to my hook, that should be the function wp_stocks_update_all_stocks().

Additionally I have tried wp_mail outside the cron job and works perfectly well. No matter what I try, the cron job never runs as it should. I tried to run the cron manually from the previous plugin and also loading multiple times http://localhost:8888/wp-cron.php?doing_cron. Nothing works. It seems that a) It has no function attached to run or b)The function can not be accessed by the cron.

I have tried the previous piece of code in a local copy of the production website and also in a clean local Wordpress installation. Same issue everywhere.

I no longer have more ideas to debug the problem. Some helping hand?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I have tried to move the previous piece of code to theme's functions.php and by doing so everything works well! Any idea why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the problem. It was shamefully simple.

I was running that piece of code from a php file that actually is a custom template being used by the plugin I'm creating. This template file is not a required file by the plugin, instead I load the template in certain occasions if needed.
Because of that, the function wp_stocks_update_all_stocks was not loaded outside the template, so WP Cron was unable to find it.

Problem solved by moving that piece of code in the main plugin .php file.